# Encode values in a NameValueCollection C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, namevaluecollection

I have a name value collections which is passed into a method to send to another system via a web client.

```
public string DoExtendedTransferAsString(string operation, NameValueCollection query, FormatCollection formats)
{
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    client.QueryString = query;
    client.QueryString["op"] = operation;
    client.QueryString["session"] = SessionId;
    using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url))
    {
        FormatCollection formats = new FormatCollection(stream);
    }
    return formats;
}
```

I need to run  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode on all the values inside the NameValueCollection but I am unsure how to. NB I cannot change the calling code so it have to be a NameValueCollection.

Thanks

Comment: @Liviu M Sorry I thought I was being specific, I want to do this to the values in a NameValueCollection. I tried  for (int i = 0; i < query.Count;i++)
            {
                query[i] = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(query[i]);
                i++;
            } It didnt work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
myCollection.AllKeys
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(k => myCollection[k] = 
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myCollection[k]));
```

Comment: FYI for anyone using this the solution requires linq not something I noticed straight away.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

```
class MyNewClass
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         String myString;
         Console.WriteLine("Enter a string having '&' or '\"'  in it: ");
         myString=Console.ReadLine();
         String myEncodedString;
         // Encode the string.
         myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
         Console.WriteLine("HTML Encoded string is "+myEncodedString);
         StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
         // Decode the encoded string.
         HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);
         Console.Write("Decoded string of the above encoded string is "+
                        myWriter.ToString());
      }
   }
```

You do the encoding part for each value in the collection in a for/foreach loop.

If this is not what you were looking for please be more explicit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will accomplish what you want...

```
    public string DoExtendedTransferAsString(string operation, NameValueCollection query, FormatCollection formats)
    {
        foreach (string key in query.Keys)
        {
            query[key] = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(query[key]);
        }

        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        client.QueryString = query;
        client.QueryString["op"] = operation;
        client.QueryString["session"] = SessionId;
        using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        {
            FormatCollection formats = new FormatCollection(stream);
        }
        return formats;
    }
```

Note the foreach I added in there, you're just iterating through all the keys, grabbing each item using the key and calling HtmlEncode on it and putting it right back.

Comment: Unfortunately not I get InvalidOperationException - Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.